# CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, css

I would like to use Validation (CSS 3.0) instead of CSS 2.1 for Visual Studio 2010. I've scanned through SO and noticed a comment saying that 3.0 wasn't finalized so it wasn't available for 2008, but was unsure if this applied to 2010.

Do I just not use CSS 3?

Comment: What's the point of using it?  All the major browsers support a subset of it.  A very good subset that many of us like to take advantage of.  We're moving forward.

Comment: @František Žiačik Try CSS3 PIE to get older versions of IE working retroactively, too. http://www.css3pie.com

Answer (score 32):

Microsoft developers have released an update to the web standards to include CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio.

Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

After a simple installation, you will have the CSS 3.0 option in Visual Studio.

(The toolbar command is called "Cascading Style Sheet Version for Validation", and is on the "Style Sheet" toolbar.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: read the reviews before you install this add on. It will cause a lot of other problems. I recommend not installing it as it is very buggy.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to wait for the service pack, check this out:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Discussions

Worked great for me, although I needed to consult the Q & A for some installation tips.

Comment: Works great.  The installer didn't write its goodies to the registry. It may be that you need to run the installer "as administrator".  Otherwise running the following reg file finishes off the install:
`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages\{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"File"="css30.xml"
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"`

Comment: +1 This installer did the trick for me, just ran it and it worked without the need for any reg hacks or running as admin.

Comment: +1. Reg file did the trick (CSS3 validation wasn't working otherwise, even when installed as admin.) Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I looked a couple months ago and couldn't find CSS3 support either. I just use the W3C online validation tool.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Web Developer 2010 Express use this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0\Packages\{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5] "File"="css30.xml" "Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
```

Comment: Not very helpful... Use this where what how when why? Maybe you could explain how to use "this"?

Comment: @snaplemouton It looks like you would open the registry editor and add the two key/value pairs he's provided.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for Visual Web Developer Express 2010:

1. Install this package.
2. Find in registry any key with css21.xml
3. Save keys as .reg
4. Edit keys changing "css21.xml" by "css30.xml" and "CSS 2.1" by "CSS 3.0"
5. Save it
6. Execute .reg files and click YES to add the new keys to the registry
7. You're done!!

Example:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0_Config\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
"File"="css30.xml"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
"File"="css30.xml"

[HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0_Config\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
"File"="css30.xml"

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0_Config\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
"File"="css30.xml"

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-819682056-1984509207-1467669795-1000\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\10.0_Config\Packages{A764E895-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5]
"Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"
"File"="css30.xml"