# Applying text-wrap using css

Tags: css, asp.net, word-wrap

im trying to apply text wrap to td (table data) using:

```
.gvUpdatesStyle .updateSummary {width:200px; white-space:normal;}
```

But it isnt working and the td is going above 200px.

Edit: Here is the html, but please note that this is generated by the GridView:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvUpdates" rules="all" class="marginLeftRightBottom10px center gvUpdatesStyle">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col">Update Id</th><th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Text</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvUpdates','Select$0')">17</a></td><td>29 ta' Awissu</td><td class="updateSummary">fgdfgdfgdfgfd</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvUpdates','Select$1')">18</a></td><td>29 ta' Awissu</td><td class="updateSummary">dfgdfgdfgfdg</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvUpdates','Select$2')">4</a></td><td>27 ta' Awissu</td><td class="updateSummary">dsfsdfdsfdfgfdgfdgfd</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvUpdates','Select$3')">5</a></td><td>27 ta' Awissu</td><td class="updateSummary">jkljl</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvUpdates','Select$4')">0</a></td><td>15 ta' Awissu</td><td class="updateSummary">testlol</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Edit: With further testing, i found out that it doesnt actually work with really long input, and appears as so:

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your HTML.

Comment: Please  see again... it isnt working 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.gvUpdatesStyle .updateSummary td {width:200px; white-space:normal;}
```

This explicitly applies the styling to the `td` elements that match your class selectors `.gvUpdatesStyle` and `.updateSummary`

**EDIT:** Based on your newly posted HTML, it looks like you're just over-selecting.  this worked for me

```
.gvUpdatesStyle td {width:200px; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

Although, now that I try it, it works with the other selectors you previously posted as well:

```
.gvUpdatesStyle .updateSummary {width:200px; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

***EDIT #42:*** This works in chrome, firefox *and* IE

```
.gvUpdatesStyle .updateSummary { width:200px; max-width:200px; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

Comment: Odd.  As @Diodeus said, could you paste into your question the HTML where your table is?  If anything jumps out at me at that point, I can update my answer to see if I can help you out.

Comment: I tried using word-wrap but i dont have it in my vistual studio css syntax. Do you know why? Up top it says im using css 2.1.

Comment: Ah, it was introduced in CSS3.  check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010) for how to change your Visual studio CSS syntax to 3.0.  Sorry to give you the run-around =)

Comment: I installed that, and it works fine, thanks!

Even thou i still dont have "word-wrap" in my intellisense, i did test out other css 3 features like "border-color" and they did show up.

Comment: Heh, I only tested IE (lame of me, huh?).  Try the updated styling out.  Had to add the `max-width` property

Answer (score 0):

There is no whitespace in your element text so the opportunity to wrap is not presented.

See the white space processing here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space

EDIT: Note the same thing in this example page:http://jsbin.com/equday/edit#preview where the text goes outside the border for the container.

Comment: I see, so how would i go about doing it please?