# Hiding horizontal scrollbars in html and css?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm trying to hide the horizontal scroll bars on my web page.
I've tried using "overflow-x:hidden" but Visual Studio says that overflow-x is not a known CSS property name.

I'm also using overflow:auto which took care of the vertical scroll bar but not the horizontal.

Help?

Comment: Don't worry, overflow-x:hidden will work in most browsers. It's css3 property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overflow properties are genuine and are in the CSS3 draft here:

[W3C CSS3 Box Model Page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x)

overflow:auto will only hide a scrollbar if the content *fits* in that direction, i.e. it will hide the vertical scrollbar if the contents are shorter than the parent container in the Y-dimension. There are some illustrations on this page which explain it better than I can!

http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x` is not a valid *CSS2* property, but is it valid *CSS3*. Can you tell your VS to check for CSS3 rather than CSS2?
(Whether you can, depends on the version of the VS.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is probably validating against the CSS2 schema, and overflow-x is a CSS3 attribute. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530826.aspx)

You have some options:

1. Change VS to validate against CSS3. I believe there is a download from the VS tools page that will enable this. (**Edit:** The link can be found here: [CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010))
2. Ignore the red underline. You can use the attribute, VS is just telling you that it isn't valid for CSS2. Just be aware that any browser that doesn't support CSS3 will also ignore the attribute.
3. Use the vendor specific attributes, such as -ms-overflow-x, as described in the MSDN article. I would only use this option as a last resort, as you'll have to test each one in all the different browsers you want to support.