# button radius is not working

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I am learning CSS, and Ajax border radius is not working in ASP.NET it shows a error like `border radius is not a known css property name.`

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: VS2010 is likely set to validate against CSS2.1 rather than CSS3.0 ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: That's not an error, that is only a warning that the CSS2.1 validation engine doesn't know that attribute. But it still works as expected when running the project.

Answer (score 5):

This is because your visual studio 2010 CSS validator is set to 2.1 or lower and `border-radius` added in CSS3. This is just a warning, so it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Morpheus is right. And some other browsers also does not support that
The best approach is to duplicate each property something like this.

```
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

You can check browsers compatibilty here [Border Properties, Values & Browser Support](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-border-properties)

**or**
the **BEST** way is just to **IGNORE IT** because it still works the way it is. :)