# How to update current css version in asp.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, css

I had the same question that has been already asked here **[CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010)** and try to follow one of the solution by installing **CSS 3 Intellisense Schema**.

The installation completed successfully and after installation a new option for **CSS 3.0** added in **Cascading Style Sheet Version For Validation** drop-down in VS IDE.

But the option **CSS 3.0** is not active i.e. it is not selectable in drop-down.

I have checked for registry entries, there are necessary entries available in `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages\{A764E895-518D‌​-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Schemas\Schema 5] "File"="css30.xml" "Friendly Name"="CSS 3.0"`

I am not able to figure out what is the problem behind this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should install vs2010 sp1? I was having the same problem the other day and I installed sp1, It was solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help..When i am trying to install vs2010 sp1 every time installer generates error message **KB2635973 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.  Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=225649 for more details.**. Currently i have **Visual Studio2010 Ultimate
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel**

Comment: as far as I understand it maybe because of the vs2010 folder doesn't allow to be updated without administrator's permission. can you check that if vs2010 folder is allowed to be altered by any user in the computer?

Comment: Thanks..you suggetion works for me.The dropdown value for CSS3.0 is active now.