# VS 2010 SP1 Cascading Style Sheet Disable

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

i am new bie i installed vs 2010 sp1 along with css3 installer but in my visual studio cascading style sheet version for validation is disable and unable to check its version or select css3.

i searched it but unable to find any solution.

Hopes for your suggestion

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft developers have released an update to the web standards to include CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio.

Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

After a simple installation, you will have the CSS 3.0 option in Visual Studio.

(The toolbar command is called "Cascading Style Sheet Version for Validation", and is on the "Style Sheet" toolbar.)

refer [CSS 3.0 in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810401/css-3-0-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: After following above procedure I can see html 5 option but "Cascading Style Sheet Version for Validation" is still disable :(

Comment: After opening css file i can see it CSS3 is there thanks alot

Comment: glad to help you :)